# XNA - Dice Check to see if player rolled the number 6

Tags: c#, xna, dice

I'm making a "simple game" in c# XNA. I have a roll button and two players. 
What I want to happen is each time you press that roll button the number that was generated equals 6 that same player is able to roll again. I have tried everything form loops and if-else statements.

```
public void DiceCheck()
    {
        if (randomNum == 6)
        {
            if (playerTurn) //Intial value of bool playerTurn is equal to true: Which means player 1 turn
            {
                playerTurn = true; //Allow player 1 to roll again
            }

            else if (playerTurn == false) // Player 2 turn
            {
                playerTurn = false; //Allow player 2 to roll again
            }
        }
    }
```

I also have something to adds every time the player rolls

```
player2turn++;
player1turn++;
```

When i insert it for both players it adds 2 to the roll number each time the player gets a 6. I want it to generate the 6 then have the player click to roll again. But it doesn't work the way I want.

Comment: The code you have added is not very helpful. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and especially [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: 1. It looks like you were expecting DiceCheck to have an Else if the randomNum != 6 that you want to flip player turns. ie. playerTurn = !playerTurn;
2. there's code missing here that is the "game loop" that is also probably missing some logic but it isn't clear what's wrong with it as it's not listed.

Comment: @theoretical can you show me an example of what you mean. I don't quite understand what your trying to say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void GameLoop(Random dice) 
{
    int randomNum = 0; 
    int turn = 0;
    while(true)
    {
         randomNum = dice.Next(1,7); //next turn roll
         Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Player {0} rolled a {1}", turn%2 + 1, randomNum));
         if(!CheckForReroll(randomNum)) // if it's a reroll don't change player's turns
         {
             turn++;
         }

         if(turn == 10) break; //made up rules to stop at turn 10 so we don't loop infinitely
    }
}

public bool CheckForReroll(int randomNum)
{
    return randomNum == 6;
}
```